# Unable to create folders from django app with docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine, django-2.2

I am unable to create folder through the below command when my django app is running through the container is running.

```
os.makedirs(path)
```

The same command is able create when i run my django project from command prompt locally without docker.

my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6.9-stretch
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENVC_FORCE_ROOT true
RUN mkdir /src
RUN mkdir /static
WORKDIR /src
ADD ./src /src

RUN pip install -r requirements.pip
CMD python manage.py collectstatic --no-input;python manage.py migrate; gunicorn specextractor.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000
```

when in my views.py i used to create the folders with the username whoever logged into the application. The functionality is working when running without docker , but it fails when running through docker container.

Any suggestion would be really helpful.

Comment: Please share your ```docker run``` command

Comment: Why do you think it fails?

Comment: docker run -d -p 9500:8000 <imange_name> @ozlevka